# Save data to cache using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, caching

I'm working on an api, which I get the data from the db then display as json. The data is big and increases every second, I manage to lessen the load by saving it in localStorage on first load then just load the latest data on next fetch then add it to the localStorage. My problem is, it reached the max size of data. Is there a way to do it on php?

**JS**

```
if(index == 0){
    localStorage.setItem("figureChart1-"+aid, JSON.stringify(data));

    var arrseries1 = data['B5'];
    var arrseries2 = data['B6'];
    var datetime = data['datetime'];
} else {
    var chart1Json = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'figureChart1-'+aid ) );
    var obj = {};
    obj['id'] = chart1Json['id'].concat(data['id']);
    obj['datetime'] = chart1Json['datetime'].concat(data['datetime']);
    obj['B5'] = chart1Json['B5'].concat(data['B5']);
    obj['B6'] = chart1Json['B6'].concat(data['B6']);

    localStorage.setItem("figureChart1-"+aid, JSON.stringify(obj));

    var arrseries1 = obj['B5'];
    var arrseries2 = obj['B6'];
    var datetime = obj['datetime'];
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to cache data in PHP. However, that won't help your front end application since it would still need to fetch it from the server on each page that needs it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, can you point me to some php tuts, I just need a simple code to make me started..

Comment: Just google on "php caching" or similar and you should find a lot of info.